# Does javascript by default have support for UTF-8

Tags: java, javascript, utf-8

I want to know whether javascript is by default UTF-8 compliant or not. If no, then how to make it UTF-8 compliant.

I am sharing you the snapshot, i have used german charterers in input type email as :  αβγδεζηθ in the image shown below, which when entered shows ok, but after the request is made to java to save this value in database, the value in this field shows unknown charterers.

[image]

Is this javascript issue or java issue ..

Comment: I'd say that depends on the implementation.

Comment: Lets take it like this, I've never seen an implementation which didn't default to UTF-8 for JavaScript.

Comment: @Cerbrus .. so what could we use in java script to make it utf8 compliant. is there any library we have to use for this task ..

Comment: vermaraj, why is this a concern? Like @jAndy said: I've yet to see a implementation that doesn't default, not to mention support UTF-8 for JS.

Comment: I almost, on sheer instinct, removed the "java" tag to say a comment like "javascript isn't java". Than I realised you really are using Java on your server!

Comment: JavaScript has issues with high pane Unicode characters (e.g. ). German should not be an issue. Sorry, the bug is your code.

Comment: @ Niet the Dark Absol : yes i am using jsp, struts for server side and JavaScript for client side and c++. the struts and c++ communicate through web service for which soap client is used.

Comment: That's not German, those are greek letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript supports unicode.

Proof:

```
 ﾟωﾟﾉ=/｀ｍ´）ﾉ~┻━┻//*´∇｀*/['_'];o=(ﾟｰﾟ)=_=3;c=(ﾟΘﾟ)=(ﾟｰﾟ)-(ﾟｰﾟ);(ﾟДﾟ)=(ﾟΘﾟ)=(o^_^o)/(o^_^o);(ﾟДﾟ)={ﾟΘﾟ:'_',ﾟωﾟﾉ:((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ],ﾟｰﾟﾉ:(ﾟωﾟﾉ+'_')[o^_^o-(ﾟΘﾟ)],ﾟДﾟﾉ:((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[ﾟｰﾟ]};(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟΘﾟ]=((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3)+'_')[c^_^o];(ﾟДﾟ)['c']=((ﾟДﾟ)+'_')[(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)-(ﾟΘﾟ)];(ﾟДﾟ)['o']=((ﾟДﾟ)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ];(ﾟoﾟ)=(ﾟДﾟ)['c']+(ﾟДﾟ)['o']+(ﾟωﾟﾉ+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ]+((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3)+'_')[ﾟｰﾟ]+((ﾟДﾟ)+'_')[(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[(ﾟｰﾟ)-(ﾟΘﾟ)]+(ﾟДﾟ)['c']+((ﾟДﾟ)+'_')[(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)]+(ﾟДﾟ)['o']+((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ];(ﾟДﾟ)['_']=(o^_^o)[ﾟoﾟ][ﾟoﾟ];(ﾟεﾟ)=((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ]+(ﾟДﾟ).ﾟДﾟﾉ+((ﾟДﾟ)+'_')[(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[o^_^o-ﾟΘﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ]+(ﾟωﾟﾉ+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ];(ﾟｰﾟ)+=(ﾟΘﾟ);(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]='\\';(ﾟДﾟ).ﾟΘﾟﾉ=(ﾟДﾟ+ﾟｰﾟ)[o^_^o-(ﾟΘﾟ)];(oﾟｰﾟo)=(ﾟωﾟﾉ+'_')[c^_^o];(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ]='\"';(ﾟДﾟ)['_']((ﾟДﾟ)['_'](ﾟεﾟ+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ]+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(c^_^o)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(c^_^o)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(o^_^o))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(c^_^o)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(o^_^o))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(o^_^o))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ])(ﾟΘﾟ))('_');
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AVnL4/)

The above code prooves that js indeed supports unicode. The above code alerts "Hello World" and is taken from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/307/obfuscated-hello-world)

So, it is not js' fault. Fault is somewhere else, or the system is unable to show those characters.

Comment: You still can use JavaScript (with its Unicode support) wrong so that it does not send UTF8.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is definitely UTF-8 compliant.

However, there are many points of failure for UTF-8. You will need to make sure that your server-side code can handle UTF-8. Then check that your database columns use UTF-8 as their character set. Then ensure that the *connection* between your server-side code and your database is using UTF-8.

The "conversion" of characters to `?`s suggests to me that it's the database that's missing encoding information.

Comment: I understand, because i think the database is already UTF-8 set. I think at this point only, the database is not displaying perfect characters for this input field. because there are some other input fields also which displays these german characters well. please comment

Comment: It's usually not a single component (like: "the database"), but rather happening at the connection between two layers.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript (the language) comes with Unicode support (all strings are inherently Unicode), but not with default UTF8 support. That is part of the APIs and their implementation. For example, in a browser the DOM does support it.

When you are sending data from a browser to a server, a) you need to set the correct headers b) send the correct data and the browser will do as expected. Then, c) the server needs to *understand* this request and use the correct encoding for deserialising the data. If something does not work, ask a question that **shows your code**.